Git editor seems locked by non-existent version of VS code
In Windows 11, on Git I can create new commit messages, but cannot edit existing ones. When I type:
git rebase -i HEAD~3
I get the answer:
\Users\fvila\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\_\Code.exe" --wait: line 1: C:
\Users\fvila\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\_\Code.exe: No such file or directory

error: There was a problem with the editor 
'"C:\Users\fvila\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\_\Code.exe" --wait'.

I don't have any VScode installation under "C:\Users\fvila\AppData".
In my VSCode app, an extension that edits commit messages does not work either.
More information: when I type
code --version 
I get an answer of:

[72564:0712/090425.595:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: Access is denied. (0x5)

[72564:0712/090425.605:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(205)] Unable to create cache

[72564:0712/090425.605:ERROR:gpu_disk_cache.cc(673)] Gpu Cache Creation failed: -2

[72564:0712/090428.005:ERROR:service_worker_storage.cc(1933)] Failed to delete the database: Database IO error

[main 2024-07-12T07:04:31.323Z] vscode-file: Refused to load resource c:\Program_files_plus\VSCode\resources\app\extensions\theme-seti\icons\seti.woff from vscode-file: protocol (original URL: vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program_files_plus/VSCode/resources/app/extensions/theme-seti/icons/seti.woff)

[69464:0712/090431.482:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: Access is denied. (0x5)

[69464:0712/090431.482:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(205)] Unable to create cache

[2672:0712/090625.963:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(523)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
[main 2024-07-12T07:06:38.882Z] Extension host with pid 10772 exited with code: 0, signal: unknown.

[main 2024-07-12T07:06:39.829Z] Extension host with pid 80892 exited with code: 0, signal: unknown.


What's the output of which code and git config --show-origin core.editor?

which code: /c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/code

git config --show-origin core.editor
file:C:/Users/fvila/.gitconfig  "C:\Users\fvila\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code_\Code.exe" --wait

I guess this means it's the git config that needs changing? I just changed the git config using git config --global core.editor "/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/code", but the problem persists

The value of core.editor points to the wrong path. Edit the file C:/Users/fvila/.gitconfig and change the path to just code --wait. You can run code /c/users/fvila/.gitconfig to start the edit.

That seems to work! If you put that in an answer I will mark it as solving the question.

After checking the output of which code and git config --show-origin core.editor, we know that core.editor points to a wrong path.
As there are spaces in the absolute path to code or code.exe, it would be a nightmare to use git config to update the value of core.editor. It's recommended to edit the global gitconfig file C:/Users/fvila/.gitconfig, by code /c/users/fvila/.gitconfig or notepad /c/users/fvila/.gitconfig.
Because the path to code.exe is in the environment variable $PATH (inferred from the output of which code), we can just set editor = code --wait instead of specifying its absolute path.
